# C++/CLI projects(compiling fine under .Net v4.7.2 & CLR, giving "Error C3699 '^': cannot use this indirection on type", under /clr:netcore & .Net 6

Tags: .net-core, c++-cli, .net-6.0, clr

I'm new to Microsoft Environment, so please accept my apologies if I've posted wrong queries or tags.
I've a set of C++/CLI projects that are working fine with .net framework v4.7.2 and /CLR support, now I've received a requirement of migrating the .net tech stack to /CLR:NetCore and .Net v6.0. When I changed the properties of project that are using managed code using the hat operator '^', almost every line with managed code is giving the "Error C3699   '^': cannot use this indirection on type"
e.g. a line of code as follows :

System::Net::Mail::SmtpClient^ smtpClient = gcnew System::Net::Mail::SmtpClient(gcnew System::String(serverAddress));

is causing this error :error C3699: '^': cannot use this indirection on type 'System::ComponentModel::AsyncOperation'

another example:

following line of code

System::Net::Mail::MailMessage^ message = gcnew System::Net::Mail::MailMessage(from, to);

is causing the error : "error C3699: '^': cannot use this indirection on type 'System::Collections::Specialized::NameValueCollection'"

To use different classes, I installed the Mailkit Nuget package in my C++ project and wrote a simple piece of code like :

MimeKit::MimeMessage^ l_eMail = gcnew MimeKit::MimeMessage();
l_eMail->From->Add(gcnew MailboxAddress(gcnew System::String(""), gcnew System::String("ABC@XYZ.com")));

the second line giving the compilation error :
error C3699: '^': cannot use this indirection on type 'System::Net::Mail::MailAddressCollection'

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the "System" reference to the C++ project which was clashing with the specific managed classes like SmtpClient, SqlClient etc, under .NetCore and .Net 6 environment.
Removing the "System" reference and installing the NuGet packages for missing/obsolete classes resolved my indirection error.